# Expresión regular con caracteres diferentes

Tags: java

He de realizar el siguiente método:
si alguno de los caracteres de la cadena de bases
recibida como argumento no es el carácter C, T, G o A, entonces setBases no
debe asignar la cadena recibida como parámetro al atributo bases y, en su lugar,
debe devolver una excepción de tipo Exception con el mensaje "[ERROR] DNA's
pattern is incorrect".
En caso contrario, sí que debe asignar el valor recibido. Todos los caracteres se
deben asignar en mayúsculas, aunque se permite que la cadena pasada como
argumento pueda tener caracteres en mayúscula y minúscula.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public void setBases(String bases) throws Exception {

        String regex = "[^acgt]";

        if (bases.matches(regex)) {
                throw new Exception("[ERROR] DNA's pattern is incorrect");
            } else {
                this.bases = bases.toUpperCase();
            }
    }
```

No encuentro el error por el que me falla el siguiente test:

```
void testConstructorGetterSetterException() {
        try{
            Exception ex = assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> new DNA("HHJ"));
            assertEquals("[ERROR] DNA's pattern is incorrect", ex.getMessage());

            ex = assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> dna.setBases("AGTCGGGAGFA"));
            assertEquals("[ERROR] DNA's pattern is incorrect", ex.getMessage());

        }catch(Exception e) {
            fail("testConstructorGetterSetter failed");
        }
    }
```

El siguiente test si me lo da correcto:

```
void testConstructorGetterSetter() {
        try{
            dna = new DNA("TGAC");
            assertEquals("TGAC", dna.getBases());

            dna = new DNA("cCTAGGCTACGGCTACGctagcCTGAtcagt");
            assertEquals("CCTAGGCTACGGCTACGCTAGCCTGATCAGT", dna.getBases());

            dna.setBases("CGAGTAGTAa");
            assertEquals("CGAGTAGTAA", dna.getBases());

        }catch(Exception e) {
            fail("testConstructorGetterSetter failed");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, no edites tu pregunta con la respuesta correcta. Futuras personas con el mismo problema no van a entender lo que preguntas, porque acabas de borrar todo lo que estaba mal, incluso las pruebas. ¿Que estás preguntando entonces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estás utilizando el `regex` de manera correcta. `[^acgt]` matchea solamente las cadenas de 1 caracter que no tengan ni `a`, `c`, `g` y `t`. Cualquier cosa que tenga dos caracteres o más va a saltarse la validación.

Te recomiendo invertir la lógica de tu método, buscando como tal las cadenas que matchean y lanzando un error si la cadena no coincide con el patrón:

```
public void setBases(String bases) throws Exception {
        String regex = "(?i)[acgt]+";

        if (bases.matches(regex)) {
            this.bases = bases.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("[ERROR] DNA's pattern is incorrect");
        }
    }
```

Nota que agregué al regex `(?i)` para ignorar mayúsculas y minúsculas, y e invertí la lógica del `if`. El código en español se lee así:

> Si la cadena `bases` está formada por una o más letras `a`, `c`, `g` ó `t` entonces es un cadena válida. De lo contrario, lanza un error.

He probado tus los test que adjuntas y los pasa sin problemas. Recuerda agregar la validación también a tu constructor:

```
public DNA(String bases) throws Exception {
    this.setBases( bases );
}
```

Comment: Solución correcta